# fFade in loads half of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, fadein

I have a slider. When I click next button the picture changes to next. On localhost it's working perfect. On server, some of images fadein half of it. I have 39 picture to slide. The picture size is about 480 kb. (728x500 pixel all of it). (picture names: 0.png 1.png ----> 38.png)

I didn't put css codes in order to prevent to much code lines.

Here is JS code:

```
var res = 1;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#slider>img").fadeOut();
    $("#slider>img#0").fadeIn();

    function nextPic() {
        if (res > 38) // redirect to some page.
            $("#slider > img").fadeOut();
        $("#slider > img#" + res).fadeIn();
        res = res + 1;
    }
}
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
<div id="slider"><?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < 39; $i++) 
        echo "<img id='".$i."' src='testPlates/".$i.".png'/>"; 
?></div>
<div id="inputOne">
    <input type="button" value="Next Slide" onClick="nextPic();"/>
</div>
```

Here is the some of picture that loaded a part of it:
[image]

But the picture must look like this:
[image]

EDİT: for live demo:(there is a button below the picture div. you can click it.)

http://www.renkligorme.com/problem.php

Comment: if you need further info to explain my problem, please let me now.

Comment: Please add a demo (live example) since it's really hard to locate the problem based on the code you've provided.

Comment: Ok. i will load a demo soon. i'm on mobile phone. i will go to work soon than i will add a demo

Comment: i added live demo at the post. (for live demo:(there is a button below the picture div. you can click it.))

Comment: by the way thanks for editing my post @Philip Dernovoy, next time i will be more careful

Comment: I'm clicking the button and all the images are being fully loaded. (And they don't look like the image you've posted in your question - the images I see are for "color-blind" tests)

Comment: could it because of my internet connection speed? my connection speed is 1m/bit

Comment: at my computer, i couldn't see some of my images, or i see some images a part of it. The picture that i added at the post is for example.

Comment: i went to my friend's home and i tried it there. it worked. So the problem must be my connection speed. so many thanks to everyone. i worked so hard to find the problem and i couldn't find it. thanks to @Ofir Baruch. From know i will try my pages that has problem at another internet provider.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of my connection speed. So, from now, i will test my pages that has problem at another internet provider